# Simple Visualforce Controller: an IF condition inside the "rendered" parameter doesn't work as expected

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

Dear developers and friends,
I'm getting crazy with Visualforce. It's probably because after a few months I keep forgetting my own findings. Here is my problem:

**### I have a VF page, and a very simple controller. If I try to show the value of a boolean variable (set by a controller) via *outputText*, what I see on the screen is what I expect. However, if I try to check the value of the variable in a *"rendered"* parameter, I get unexpected results.**

Let me share some code.

Controller:

```
public Integer DMHcountTotalRecords{get; set;}
public Boolean isDMHcountPositive {get; set;}
public void getDMHcountTotRecords(){
   DMHcountTotalRecords = 5;  
   isDMHcountPositive = 5 > 0;
}
```

Easy-peasy. And now, outputs that I obtain with different VF page's code.

**1. Expected behaviour**

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!DMHcountTotalRecords}"/>
</apex:outputText> 
<apex:outputText value="{!isDMHcountPositive}" />
```

Results on screen: **5true**

**2. Unexpected behaviour**

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!DMHcountTotalRecords}"/>
</apex:outputText> 
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(isDMHcountPositive, true, false)}">TEST</apex:outputText>
```

Results on screen: **5**

The word "TEST" is not shown.

**3. Unexpected behaviour**

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!DMHcountTotalRecords}"/>
</apex:outputText> 
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(isDMHcountPositive, true, false)}">TEST</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText value="{!isDMHcountPositive}" />
```

Results on screen: **5false**

The word "TEST" is not shown and *isDMHcountPositive* becomes *false*.

The big and simple question is: why? Why the cases 2 and 3 work like that and how can I use a boolean value to render a block of code in VF?

**Additional crazyness**

Even if I test *DMHcountTotalRecords*, something goes wrong:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">
    <apex:param value="{!DMHcountTotalRecords}"/>
</apex:outputText> 
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(DMHcountTotalRecords>0, true, false)}">TEST</apex:outputText>
```

In this case I cannot even save the Visualforce page. The Developer Console claims that *DMHcountTotalRecords* is *null*.